# Flutter Full page ads in PageView like Short news Way2news

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Hello Everyone I want to show Admob ads in my flutter pageview after a 5-page swipe and on the 6th page I want a full-page banner ad, if I swipe this then I can go on the 7th page of the news.

I have implemented but I am unable to get full-page banner ads, it shows 312x100 pixels size ads only.

Here is my full code.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'Helper/ad_helper.dart';
import 'Models/news.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Tedd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeddState createState() => _TeddState();
}

class _TeddState extends State<Tedd> {
  List<NewsModel> _newsList = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  late BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;
  int currentPage = 1;
  bool hasReachedEnd = false;
  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  _getAllNews(currentPage) async {
    var articles = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://pkbhai.com/myprojects/kids-stories/api/all-stories?page=${currentPage}"));
    var result = json.decode(articles.body);
    var newDataLength = result['data'].length;
    if (newDataLength == 0) {
      setState(() {
        hasReachedEnd = true;
      });
    }
    result['data'].forEach((data) {
      var news = NewsModel();
      news.id = data["id"];
      news.articleTitle = data["name"];
      news.articleDetails = data["details"];
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _newsList.add(news);
        });
      }
    });

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
  }

  void handleNext() {
    _pageController.addListener(() async {
      if (_pageController.page?.toInt() == _newsList.length - 1) {
        setState(() {
          currentPage += 1;
        });
        _getAllNews(currentPage);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (_) {
          setState(() {
            _isBannerAdReady = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
          _isBannerAdReady = false;
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    _bannerAd.load();
    _getAllNews(currentPage);
    handleNext();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _newsList.length > 0
          ? PageView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: _pageController,
              itemCount: _newsList.length + (isLoading ? 1 : 0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == _newsList.length && hasReachedEnd) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  );
                }
                if (index == _newsList.length && !hasReachedEnd) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0) {
                  return Container(
                    child:
                        // if (_isBannerAdReady)
                        Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                        height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),  // also tried 1000, but not worked
                        child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade400,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      child: PageView(
                        reverse: true,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            _newsList[index].articleDetails!,
                            maxLines: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(_newsList[index].articleTitle!),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You used

`size: AdSize.banner,`

this is the size parameter, AdSize.banner has size of 312x100
You can check out all available size for banner on https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/banner

And i think there is no full page Ad other then Interstitial ads and if you want to implement full page ad then you need to use Native Advance ad with custom ui in both android and swift.